# Generation of complex SOAP Envelope in accordance with OASIS WS Security specification using KSOAP2?

Tags: android, ksoap2, ws-security, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I am new to Android Development. I need to consume a .NET web service which is designed in accordance with [OASIS Web Services Security specification](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=wss).

I am using KSOAP2 latest API to generate SOAP envelope. I need to send SOAP request strictly in below format

### Required SOAP Envelope

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">    

<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>http://myXYZ_Action</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>XYZ</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:Address>http://something.com</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To>http://something.asmx</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="XYZ">
            <wsu:Created>2012-03-02T14:03:24Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2012-03-02T14:08:24Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-XYZ">
            <wsse:Username>XYZ</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XYZ</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce>XYZ==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2012-03-02T14:04:24Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <DoSomeThing xmlns="http://something"/></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

After doing loads of searches and referring to online help, i have been able to generate SOAP request using KSOAP2 like given below

### KSOAP2 Generated Request dump

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<v:Header>
    <Action>http://myXYZ_Action</Action>
    <MessageID>XYZ</MessageID>
    <ReplyTo>
        <Address>http://something.com</Address>
    </ReplyTo>
    <To>http://something.asmx</To>
    <Security mustUnderstand="1">
        <Timestamp Id="XYZ">
            <Created>2012-03-02T14:03:24Z</Created>
            <Expires>2012-03-02T14:08:24Z</Expires>
        </Timestamp>
        <n0:UsernameToken xmlns:n0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <Username>XYZ</Username>
            <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XYZ</Password>
            <Nonce>XYZ==</Nonce>
            <Created>2012-03-06T00:04:24Z</Created>
        </n0:UsernameToken>
    </Security>
</v:Header>
<v:Body>
    <GetActualDateTime xmlns="http://something/" />
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

### My Code (This is just a POC code hence no coding standards/best practices followed)

For security purpose certain infomation have been masked.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://myXYZ_Action"; 
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "DoSomeThing"; 
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://something/"; 
    private static final String URL = "http://xyz.asmx/wse"; 
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        try
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

            envelope.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            envelope.xsi= SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSI;
            envelope.env= SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENV;

            //Prepare header
            envelope.headerOut = new Element[5];
            envelope.headerOut[0] = buildActionHeader();
            envelope.headerOut[1] = buildMessageIDHeader();
            envelope.headerOut[2] = buildReplyToHeader();
            envelope.headerOut[3] = buildToHeader();
            envelope.headerOut[4] = buildSecurityHeader();


            envelope.dotNet=true; 
            envelope.implicitTypes=true;
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL); 

            androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 

           //To be removed. This is just to check the request and response. 
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String req = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String res = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            //End 

            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse(); 

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String[] results = (String[])  result; 

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private Element buildActionHeader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //<wsa:Action> Element
        Element actionElement = new Element().createElement("", "Action"); 
        actionElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "http://myXYZ_Action");
        return actionElement;
    }

    private Element buildMessageIDHeader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //<wsa:MessageID> Element
        Element messageIDElement = new Element().createElement("", "MessageID"); 
        messageIDElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "XYZ");        
        return messageIDElement;
    }

    private Element buildReplyToHeader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //<wsa:Address> Element
        Element addressElement = new Element().createElement("", "Address"); 
        addressElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "http://something.com");

        //<wsa:ReplyTo> Element
        Element replyToElement = new Element().createElement("", "ReplyTo"); 
        replyToElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, addressElement);
        return replyToElement;
    }

    private Element buildToHeader() {
        Element toElement = new Element().createElement("", "To"); 
        toElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "http://something.asmx");

        return toElement;
    }

    private Element buildSecurityHeader() {
        Element securityElement = new Element().createElement(null, "Security"); 
        securityElement.setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand", "1");

        //<wsu:Timestamp> Element
        Element timestampElement = new Element().createElement(null, "Timestamp");
        timestampElement.setAttribute(null, "Id", "XYZ");
        //<wsu:Created> Element
        Element createdElement = new Element().createElement(null, "Created"); 
        createdElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "2012-03-06T00:01:24Z");

        //<wsu:Expires> Element
        Element expiresElement = new Element().createElement(null, "Expires"); 
        expiresElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "2012-03-06T00:05:24Z");

        timestampElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, createdElement);
        timestampElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,expiresElement);

        Element usernameTokenElement = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken");

        Element usernameElement = new Element().createElement(null, "Username"); 
        usernameElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "XYZ");

        Element passwordElement = new Element().createElement(null, "Password"); 
        passwordElement.setAttribute(null, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
        passwordElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "XYZ");

        Element nonceElement = new Element().createElement(null, "Nonce"); 
        nonceElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "XYZ====");

        Element created2Element = new Element().createElement(null, "Created"); 
        created2Element.addChild(Node.TEXT, "2012-03-06T00:04:24Z");

        usernameTokenElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, usernameElement);
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, passwordElement);
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, nonceElement);
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, created2Element);

        securityElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, timestampElement);
        securityElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, usernameTokenElement);

        return securityElement;
    }

}
```

### I did not find any help on my below queries. I will appreciate your expert advice on help me generate correct SOAP request ASAP plz.

### 1.How to add additional namespaces on envelope? i.e adding below attributes to envelope.

```
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
```

### 2. How to change/map correct namespaces across envelope i.e. adding xmlns:wsse, xmlns:wsu, xmlns:was namespaces in header and mapping them like as mentioned below

```
     xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

                     to 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

                       OR

         xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                       to
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

                       AND

<v:Envelope> to <soap:Envelope> ; <Action> to <wsa:Action> ; 

<n0:UsernameToken xmlns:n0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                        TO
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-XYZ">
```

Answer (score 0):

For First two, I modified the jar libraries
Otherwise I used the method addAttribute for `"wsu:Id="SecurityToken-XYZ"`.
For further questions please respond.

Answer (score 0):

xmlns:**i** this part of token doesn't matter as long as the namespace it referes to is correct

The above answer worked for me just as is ie: xmlns:i xmlns:v etc